# quick way to generate basic json metadata for nft pre reveal?

Tags: javascript, json, metadata, linux-mint, nft

just a quick question. me and a friend is making an nft collection and would like to know if there's a quick way to generate json metadata for pre reveal?

I haven't tried anything yet unless i do it manually or create loops but is there any quicker way?

Answer (score 0):

you can use hashlips engine to generate nfts from layers. It will also generate the metadata for each nft

https://github.com/HashLips/hashlips_art_engine

If you want to show prereveal, you can set a flag "hidden" to true, and if its  true you can just point to one tokenURI file through the smartcontract, so no multiple json files are needed.